# Disabling Index operations for certain tables in SQL Server 2008 R2 other than DDL trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, triggers, ddl

Is there a way to disable certian index DDL operation (create, drop and alter index) for a list of tables in MS SQL Server 2008 R2?

What I was trying to do is to create a DDL trigger that catch these events and roll them back, but it seems that all ddl trigers are after triggers and if table is very large this cause performance issues.

The trigger I am currently using is the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER index_guard
    ON DATABASE
    FOR CREATE_INDEX, DROP_INDEX, ALTER_INDEX
    AS
        DECLARE @object_name NVARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE @target_object_type NVARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE @object_type NVARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE @lookup_value NVARCHAR(100);

        DECLARE @protected_indexes TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(50))
        INSERT INTO @protected_indexes
        SELECT Name FROM (VALUES ('TABLE1/IX_IdName'), ('TABLE2/IX_NameId')) AS tbl(Name)

        SELECT @object_name = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
        SELECT @table_name = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
        SELECT @target_object_type = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectType)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
        SELECT @object_type = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]','nvarchar(max)');

        IF @object_type = 'INDEX' AND @target_object_type = 'TABLE'
        BEGIN
            SET @lookup_value = @table_name + '/' + @object_name
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @protected_indexes A WHERE A.Name = @lookup_value)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK
            END
        END
```

Comment: I'have also posted my question to SQL Server Central Forum. Here is the link: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1731743-392-1.aspx